# QML GridLayout fill doesn't work with span

Tags: qml, grid-layout

(QtQuick 2.12 on Windows)

I'm having two related problems with `GridLayout` objects, both revolving around the use of `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight` to get constant sized cells that their contents can anchor themselves to. I believe they also apply to `RowLayout` and `ColumnLayout`.

First, some of my children use `Layout.columnSpan` or `Layout.rowSpan`. But when I do this, even though the extra columns or rows are "occupied", the `fillWidth` or `fillHeight` doesn't seem to apply to the extra columns or rows. If this is W.A.D, I can't imagine why anyone would D. it this way--it looks like a bug to me. My "solution" is to create dummy items that force the other columns or rows to be filled. But this isn't without its problems. For instance, if I have a `GridLayout` with five columns, and I want to attach a child that is five columns wide (say as a title in the top row), and some of the columns are otherwise unoccupied, I can create a dummy `Item` with its `Layout` properties set to occupy those columns. But if I can't find a row in which there isn't something already spanning those columns, then the item clashes with one of the real items I want to display. This "works", but it produces an error message in the log, e.g., `QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (0, 4) already taken.`

BTW, I've found that I only need to insert enough dummy single-cell items to define all the grid boundaries. In the above example, I'd need a dummy in columns 1 and 3, because that's enough to define boundaries 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, and 3-4:

```
    0       1       2       3       4
+---------------------------------------+
|              colSpan = 5              |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
        | dummy |       | dummy |
        +-------+       +-------+
```

Second, I specify a spacing on the `GridLayout`, but sometimes I want a double-wide gap, so I treat that as just another row or column that has nothing in it, and that should therefore have a zero height or width. But when I do that, I don't get the extra spacing--it acts as if the row or column just doesn't exist. Again, W.A.D.? But why? My "solution" is to place a dummy Item into the empty row with its `Layout.fillWidth` set, but obviously not `Layout.fillHeight` (or the opposite for an empty column).

These are pretty ugly hacks, they junk up the source code, and they're error-prone. Does anyone have any better ideas on how to do either of these things? Does anyone think they could be called bugs?